# Similar function to SQL LIMIT in CRX XPATH search

Tags: search, xpath, jcr

I'm performing an XPATH search in (Day CQ) CRX, and I'm trying to limit the results returned by the query.

After reading every possible forum on the internet, I came to understanding that

```
(//my-component)[position() <= 5]
```

should return the first 5 elements that match the query, as noted [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp).

I get, *Unsupported expression with position(). Only = is supported.*

I also try last() for example, but I get all the results back.

Any help on how to limit the number of results would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using the [Query](http://www.day.com/specs/javax.jcr/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/query/Query.html) interface to run your queries, you can use the `.setLimit()` and `.setOffset()` methods to page through your results.

Comment: no I'm not. it's plain jcr xpath